# Is there cloud service or cloud software with features similiar to version control system?

Tags: cloud-service, cloud-storage

I am looking for sth which will allows me to sync files similiar to SyncToy: https://23219-presscdn-pagely.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/preview.jpg

Feature I am looking for is beeing able to select files I want to sync from all changed ones.

I dont want to sync whole drive since if data on drive became corrupted, it gonna mark it as changes and upload corrupted files into cloud without my knowledge. I might realize that after 3-4 months or even 2 years when I want to access those files, and since cloud companies allows to access filechange history for like 1 month I'd prefer rather to just not upload corrupted changes. I guess I could find company with longer access, but it would cost a lot.

Any ideas? I tried to google that, but I couldn't really find anything, only "remove sync" and "add sync" option from ODrive, but that would be kinda pain in ass to do that all the time, and I might always miss some changed files by doing that.

Currently I am using amazon cloud drive since its cheapest and dropbox for filesharing.

Comment: Github,   may be?

Comment: RaV, do you want to keep your files private, or can they be public? Also, what budget do you have?

Comment: And what OS should it sync to/from?

Comment: I want to keep my files private. I want rather cloud drive (simpler) than some git, which is more for programming projects. My data its mostly photos (I am photographer). I'll sync from windows, eventually linux, but linux is not crucial for me. Budget I want to spend is max 25$/month.